# Javascript validation, where string is compiled of only any number of spaces

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a function that will return true / false if the string in question is complied of any number of spaces. The common method of doing this is `if (string == " ")` but this only works for one space. I need a function that would resolve any number of spaces to a return statement.

example

```
if (string == " ")
if (string == "  ")
if (string == "   ")
if (string == "    ")
if (string == "     ")
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Does it need to be only spaces or would this string return true: `string = " J      "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression: `/^ +$/.test(string)`.

A regular expression is also good if you want to match any whitespace rather than just spaces (which is sometimes useful): `/^\s+$/.test(string)`. The `\s` matches all whitespace characters like `" "` and `"\t"`. So:

```
/^ +$/.test("     ");// True
/^ +$/.test("   \t\t");// False
/^\s+$/.test("      ");// True
/^\s+$/.test("    \t\t");// True
```

For reference, `"\t"` will look something like

```
"   "
```

(I think SO turned the tab into spaces, but that's more or less what it would look like.)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a simple regular expression:

```
var x = "    ";
if (x.match(/^ +$/)) {
  alert("yes");
} else {
  alert("no");
}
```

Comment: To break that regex down for you: "^" matches the beginning of  the string, " +" matches one or more space, "$" matches the end of the string.

Comment: Your way works, of course, but if you just want a true/false matches/doesn't result I'd use `.test()`.

Comment: Yes, .test() should be slightly faster

Answer (score 1):

```
function check(str)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != " ") return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think that the `str[i]` syntax does not work under older versions of IE; consider using `str.charAt(i)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
String.prototype.count=function(s1) {
    return (this.length - this.replace(new RegExp(s1,"g"), '').length) / s1.length;
}
myString.length == myString.count(' ');
```